# Converting Single Line Employee Records to Pivoted Sankey Layout

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

Looking to do the following in PowerQuery preferably in PowerBI (but am comfortable with taking advantage of Python):

I have records in this layout:

```
Employee ID, Employee Classification, Start Date, End Date
9999999, Financial-1, March 17 2008, June 7 2009
9999999, Financial-2, June 8 2009, December 2 2016
9999999, Financial-3, December 3 2016, November 12 2017
9999999, Ninja-4, November 13 2017, December 31 2018
```

I want to convert it to the following (using the dates as a parent/child):

```
Employee ID, Source, Destination
9999999, Financial-1, Financial-2
9999999, Financial-2, Financial-3
9999999, Financial-3, Ninja-4
```

Thank you, and sorry if this is a duplicate somewhere I didn't know what exactly to search for on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I would try creating a new column `NextDay` that adds one day to `End Date` and then do a self-merge matching `NextDay` with `Start Date`.

```
let
    Source = <Your Source Here>
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "NextDay", each Date.AddDays([#"End Date"],1), type date),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"NextDay"}, #"Added Custom", {"Start Date"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"Employee Classification"}, {"Destination"})
in
    #"Expanded Added Custom"
```

You can then remove unneeded columns and rename columns as desired.